# Difference between FIND_IN_SET and LIKE

Tags: mysql, performance, percona

Is there a difference in behavior or performance in choosing FIND_IN_SET over LIKE for a operation that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_1 LIKE '%string%';
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('string', column_1) > 0;
```

This is done on Percona Server.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7499438/632951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use LIKE for one very good reason. From the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) - "This function (FIND_IN_SET) does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character".

You could always use an EXPLAIN  to check on performance - but simply for the reason above, I would not use it.

[EDIT]

You could always use [LOCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate). I **strongly** recommend that you don't use MySQL's SET datatype. It's non-standard and illogical to say the least.

Comment: I can guarantee the substring i would be searching for would not have a comma. I remember looking at that doc but it didnt really provide any information to lean one way or the other. Thanks for the help, its much appreciated

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun I see that docs actually provide a lot of information to deal with. Do you need to locate where 'string' is in your set? I don't think that's your expected output, therefore LIKE would be much better.

Comment: @Vérace, What do you mean when you say *"SET datatype"*?

Comment: @Pacerier MySQL allows you to declare a datatype called SET (which is also an SQL keyword to add to the confusion). See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html). It's a breach of Codd's second rule which says that every datum should be addressable by table name, PK and field name only - not dependent on it's position in a "SET".